# Why isn't this library linking with a pragma comment?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, pragma

I'm using Fmod in a project I'm working on in Visual C++ 2008. If I include

```
../fmodapi375win/api/lib/fmodvc.lib
```

in Project->Linker->Input, it works fine, but for some reason if I use

```
#pragma comment(lib,"../fmodapi375win/api/lib/fmodvc.lib")
```

instead it works the same as if that line wasn't there: it builds with no linker errors then crashes with a stack overflow from a million access violation exceptions.

What's going on, and how can I fix it so I can define the lib in code?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you are supposed to provide the .lib in the pragma comment, but, I think the real problem is that you are calling the comment by path.  Add the path to your lib search paths, and then just use a

```
#pragma comment(lib,"fmodvc")
```

You are SUPPOSED to be able to use a path in this comment, but are you sure the ..\ path you are using is the correct path during link time?  Also make sure you are NOT compiling with the /nodefaultlib...

Let me know if this still does not work.  I've used this type of pragma a lot, with great success...

But, now that I'm pretty much trapped in the C# world, I don't get much time to even program in C++ anymore...

Comment: Stuart, I've gone back since this post, and I HAVE used the #pragma that you are using, and it does work.  You just have to make sure you ARE in fact linking from the correct directory.  My guess is ../ isn't correct, since the linker works out of the $(TargetDir) directory...  Hope this helps.  Let me know if it still does not work, and I'll dig into further even...

Comment: +1 for the observation about /nodefaultlib. It caught me off guard that this would keep '#pragma comment(lib, ...)' from working.

Answer (score 1):

Libs could be linked in another order, so symbols are resolved differently.

Answer (score 0):

Set /VERBOSE on the command line of the link.  In the GUI, you can do this on the  property page of the project -- add to the "Command Line" node under Linker.

Then it will tell you how it resolved each function -- search for a function you know should be in fmodvc.lib.

Another thing to do is to run PROCMON.EXE during the link (pre-filter so that PATH CONTAINS fmodvc.lib) -- then link.  It will tell you the exact location it found the file (and if it ever looked for it).  Get PROCMON here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Finally, if it's linking, but not loading your library (or resolving the references) -- you might have the option to force the link to succeed set -- you should turn that off.  It would be [/FORCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70abkas3.aspx) in the command line section (like /VERBOSE).

Comment: Process Monitor's going to find *statically linked* libraries?

Comment: during the link, yes.  During the link, the linker must try to open the files -- procmon will see that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely certain it's the same lib file in the two instances?

This can get very weird if you miss the fact that there are two versions of a file on your machine. I seriously suggest you search your drive for all occurrences of this file just to do a sanity check.